# Grabbing a number from Entry and doing calculations using Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm working on my final project for my Intro to Programming classes and I'm having the hardest time working with Tkinter and Python.

Here is my task:
Have a user enter their income from their paycheck. The program will then do the following calculations: What is 60% of their income for expenses, what is 10% for BOTH short-term and long-term savings and what is 20% of their paycheck for guilt-free spending?

Once the program has completed the calculations, it will then display each of these calculations so the user can make the appropriate transfers with their accounts.

**Here is the code I currently have:**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def calculate(*args):
    try:
        value = float(income.get())
        expenses.set(value * .60)
        shortSavings.set(value * .10)
        longSavings.set(value * .10)
        guiltFree.set(value * .20)

    except ValueError:
        pass

root = Tk()
root.title("Monthly Finance Calculater")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

income = StringVar()
expenses = StringVar()
shortSavings = StringVar()
longSavings = StringVar()
guiltFree = StringVar()

income_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=income)
income_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

expenses = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=expenses)
expenses.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=income).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Calculate", command=calculate).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)

income_entry.focus()
root.bind('<Return>', calculate)

root.mainloop()
```

I've been searching for days and I'm completely stuck. I don't want this done for me, but could really use some guidance and advice on how to make this work in a GUI using Tkinter.

Comment: How are you stuck? What do you need help with?

Comment: I can't get this to work lol...

Comment: _why_? What problem are you having? Is it crashing? Are the calculations coming out wrong? You need to be specific. Questions of the form "why isn't my code working?" are off topic here.

Comment: My apologies for being to vague. My main problem isn't the calculations not working, but getting Tkinter to work properly. For some reason I cannot get it to show anything when I run the code.

Comment: It won't show _anything_?

Answer (score 1):

One Problem was mentioned by Max already. The second problem is this one:

```
except ValueError:
    pass
```

It's clear why you don't get anything if you pass an exception. Use at least a print so you will get the errors shown in the console:

```
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

The last real problem that i see is that you use the variable `expenses` two times! First time as a `StringVar()` and the second time as a `Entry`. In the end you don't have a StringVar because you overwrite it. 
Also consider to label your entrys, because the user don't know what he is entering there yet. Furthermore learn how to use the debugger in eclipse, it's much easier than you think. So you can find the bugs yourself. I wish you good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, is that:

```
income_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=income)
income_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
```

and

```
expenses = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=expenses)
expenses.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky=(W, E))
```

are on the same column and row, which means one is not visible, change one of both to a different row, so it shows both the entry fields.

This might solve why you don't see anything, however I'm not sure what you mean by that.